# MKA RXSC not created/shown

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I managed to have MACsec working between two hosts by setting manually TXSC and RXSC and every thing worked like a charm.

After switching to MKA and wpa_supplicant when I do

```
root@Debian10-02:~# ip macsec show
10: macsec0: protect on validate strict sc off sa off encrypt on send_sci on end_station off scb off replay off
    cipher suite: GCM-AES-128, using ICV length 16
    TXSC: 0050000012020001 on SA 0
root@Debian10-02:~#
```

I only see the TXSC.
My wpa_supplicant's version is

```
root@Debian10-02:~# wpa_supplicant -v
wpa_supplicant v2.8-devel
Copyright (c) 2003-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
```

and the wpa_supplicant config file is the one I find in Sabrina Dubroca's article

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/06/28/whats-new-in-macsec-setting-up-macsec-using-wpa_supplicant-and-optionally-networkmanager#integration_with_wpa_supplicant

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
eapol_version=3
ap_scan=0
fast_reauth=1

network={
        key_mgmt=NONE
                eapol_flags=0
                macsec_policy=1

                mka_cak=0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF
                mka_ckn=6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A303132333435
}
```

and I launch it via

```
wpa_supplicant -i eth2 -Dmacsec_linux -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I see examples where the control interface is disabled but I'm not sure what's its real meaning.
Also I make sure there is only one instance of the wap_supplicant (at the boot the system launched it own that I had to kill)

Would anyone have a hint/advice on how to troubleshoot?
I guess a setup through wpa_supplicant should take care not only of the encryption part (TXSC) but also of the decryption one (RXSC).

Thanks,

Alex